# Problema nos arquivos após upload, no Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tenho o seguinte código para realizar upload de arquivos na minha aplicação Laravel.

**upload.blade**

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="name" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Documento *:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input  type="file" multiplename="docs[]"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**DocumentsController**

```
public function move(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->hasFile('docs')) {

        $doc = $request->file('docs');


        foreach($doc as $files)
        {

            //Recupera o nome original do arquivo
            $filename  = $files->getClientOriginalName();

            //Recupera a extensão do arquivo
            $extension = $files->getClientOriginalExtension();

            //Definindo um nome unico para o arquivo
            $name  = $filename . '.' . $extension;

            //Diretório onde será salvo os arquivos
            $destinationPath = storage_path('documents');

            //Move o arquivo para a pasta indicada
            $files->move($destinationPath, $name);
        }


        Session::flash('flash_message_success', 'Documento carregado com sucesso!');
        return redirect()->action('DocumentsController@upload');
    }
    else
    {
        Session::flash('flash_message_error', 'Arquivo não carregado. Tente novamente!');
        return redirect()->action('DocumentsController@upload');
    }

}
```

Até aí tudo bem, os arquivos são carregados para a pasta de destino, porém não é possível abri-los. Abaixo o erro de arquivos jpeg e Também recebo o erro em PDF.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Tem como abrir o .jpeg no notepad?

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno Guilherme. Estou no trabalho, assim que chegar em casa tentarei sua dica. Imagina o que possa ser? Ah, estou rodando a aplicação em Localhost, acredita que posso ter algo a ver?

Comment: @L.B.O falta permissão na pasta temporária, dependendo da configuração do seu PHP, mas, geralmente na pasta `c:\Windows\Temp` para Windows falta permissão do escrita, tem que ver o usuário do servidor que está usando.

Comment: @Virgilio provavelmente quando subir os arquivos para a hospedagem e der permissão de leitura e escrita na pasta deve funcionar. Vou testar e lhes dou um retorno. Grato pela atenção.

Comment: Então, ontem tive um problema como Wampserver. O mesmo parou de funcionar e tive que reinstala-lo. Ao configurar minha aplicação novamente realizei o teste de upload de arquivos, engraçado que o erro que estava ocorrendo parou e o código acima está funcionando normalmente.